# xsd - sequence vs choice

Tags: xml, xsd

I am confused about the XML Schema sequence
According to w3schools.com,
`The sequence element specifies that the child elements`***`must appear`***`in a sequence. Each child element can occur from`***`0`***`to any number of times.`
If each element must appear, how can it occur 0 times?  Wouldn't that break the ***must appear*** rule?

---

And another thing, what is the difference between

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element name="choiceA" type="xs:string" >
  <xs:element name="choiceB" type="xs:string" />
</xs:choice>
```

and this:

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <xs:element name="choiceA" type="xs:string" >
  <xs:element name="choiceB" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
```

can't you put any number of each element for both of these cases?  Is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The elements within a sequence must appear in the order specified in the schema. But if an element is defined with minOccurs="0" then it does not have to appear.

Here is a similar example to one that is one the w3schools.com tutorial. I have just added the minOccurs="0" to the firstname element.

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In this case valid xml elements based on this definition would be

```
<employee>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>
```

or you remove the firstname element because it has a minOccurs="0"

```
<employee>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>
```

you cannot however mix the order of the elements. So this would be invalid.

```
<employee>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
  <firstname>John</firstname>
</employee>
```

As for the difference between the choice and the sequence. The choice element only allows one of the elements to appear. So the choice could have choiceA or choiceB but not both. Whereas the way the sequence is defined each sequence element is going to have both a choiceA and a choiceB.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  However, if you set maxOccur="unbounded" for a choice, couldn't you have as many of each element as you want?

Comment: With the choice as defined: you can still only have either choiceA or choiceB but you can have as many of the choosen element you want.

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately there is another way to use choice - in case of 0 to unbounded it's possible to have multiple elements of the same type as well as none.

example:

```
 <xs:element name="module">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="active"/>
        <xs:element ref="debug"/>
        <xs:element name="name">
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

will accept following XML one:

```
<samba>
    <active>off</active>
    <name>Box</name>
</samba>
```

and will accept following XML two:

```
<samba>
    <debug>off</debug>
    <active>off</active>
    <debug>off</debug>
    <name>Box</name>
    <debug>off</debug>
</samba>
```